# regex&wildcard match and replace between certain characters

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I can search all characters with `\±*\¦` wildcard in Microsoft Word like this:
±sample word1¦ ±sample word2¦

`\±*\¦` matchs entire of characters between ± and ¦ 
And when I want to replace ± ¦ with ( ) or any other character I use this: `(^&)`
That returns to me as: (±sample word1¦).

Everything is ok with ms word but I have not found yet equivalent of regex for text editors (I use sublimetext and notepad++)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ uses boost regex flavour, to match 0 or more any characters you have to use `.*`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `±.*?¦`
- Replace with: `\($0\)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
±           # ± character, doesn't need to be escaped as it hasn't special meaning in regex
.*?         # 0 or more any character, but newline, not greedy
¦           # ¦ character, doesn't need to be escaped as it hasn't special meaning in regex. But if you use pipe `|` character then, you have to escape it: \|
```

**Replacement:**

```
\(          # opening parenthesis, have to be escaped in Notepad++
$0          # the whole match
\)          # closing parenthesis, have to be escaped in Notepad++
```

**Given:**

```
±sample word1¦ ±sample word2¦
```

**Result for given example:**

```
(±sample word1¦) (±sample word2¦)
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]